# Ethernet adapter in "lspci" but not available in "nmtui"

Tags: linux, fedora, network-interface, hardware, ethernet

How can I activate an Ethernet adapter which is visible in `lspci` but otherwise not exposed?

Messing around, I recently moved an SSD with a Fedora install from one computer to another. Without changing anything, most everything is working quite adequately-- it is great how flexible things were! However, while I can see the network interface  hardware on the new computer with `lspci`, I cannot see it in `ifconfig`.

The only interfaces I have available are the loopback and a "bridge" interface. The card is not disabled in BIOS and was working to PXE boot previously. I tried manually adding it via ifcfgs generated by `nmtui` including adding MACADDR/HWADDR fields to those, but with those in place, systemctl would fail to restart networkmanager.

Edit: In front of the system again. Strangely, when I boot with a USB NIC attached to get around this issue, it is not enumerated in `ifconfig` unless I unplug/re-plug. I am able to in BIOS specify the passthrough MAC to be the NIC1 MAC, so I have the same MAC on the USB Ethernet adapter. This doesn't solve the root issue, which I am still trying to solve.

Comment: Do you see it with `ip link` or `ifconfig -a`?  Another comupter -> another adapter -> another mac addr. Check your `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/` for config file and change mac addr there

Comment: Thanks, I don't have it in front of me but know it didn't show with "ip addr" or "ifconfig" minus the -a parameter. I tried to change the MAC in the ifcfg that existed from the previous NIC, but networkmanager would fail to start. I will check /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/ when I am near it as well.

Comment: Check if `sudo lspci -vvv` contains a kernel module for your network device. Also check `dmesg`.

Comment: Please add output of ``lspci -vvv``, ``ip link`` and also ``dmesg`` (there may be some errors)

Comment: Sure, thanks: [dmesg](https://pastebin.com/3viSPEN0), [ip_link](https://pastebin.com/82pGGdpd), [lspci_-vvv](https://pastebin.com/qqeEKbkV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your `lspci -vvv` output `Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (11) I219-LM` has **no** kernel driver in use. The kernel you have seemingly doesn't support your HW. You're running the latest released kernel for RHEL 7 which might still be *too* old.

You've got two options:

- Installing kernel 5.17.5 (this one will definitely work) or RHEL 8's kernel (may or may not work - I'm too lazy to check RHEL 8 documentation, sorry). RHEL/Fedora based distros allow to install as many kernels as possible.
- Installing the kernel-devel package and then compiling [Intel's own driver](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/14611/15817/intel-network-adapter-driver-for-pcie-intel-gigabit-ethernet-network-connections-under-linux.html?).